# Different $RANDOM results in sed when reading lines in multiple files

Tags: replace, for, random

I'm trying to run a command that will read multiple files in a directory, look at each line of each file, and whenever it reads a specific string ("gene_height") on any line it replaces 2 numbers on that line with 170-220. For example in the following:

```
        complexion={ "complexion_3" 60 "complexion_3" 132 }
        gene_height={ "normal_height" 192 "normal_height" 161 }
```

It should see "gene_height" and replace 192 and 161 with random numbers from 170 to 220, but it should leave the 60 and 132 from the earlier line alone because it does not start with "gene_height". What I currently have *almost* works, the problem is it uses the same number for everything because it's really only running $RANDOM once per file and I can't find a good way to split it to work per-line instead.

Currently I am using:

```
for f in *.txt; do sed -i -e '/\bgene_height\b/ s/ [0-9][0-9]*/ '$((169+RANDOM%51))'/g' $f; done
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Try `awk` (not sed):

```
awk '/^gene_height/{
       $3=sprintf("%.0f",(169+rand()*5))
       $5=sprintf("%.0f",(169+rand()*5))
    }1' test*.txt
```

Comment: Thank you! This put me down the right path and I found exactly what I needed through some trial and error. As a single line it came out to "awk -i inplace '/^gene_height/{ $3=sprintf("%.0f",(169+rand()*51));$5=sprintf("%.0f",(169+rand()*51)) }1' *"

Comment: Shucks I am running into one issue. In the real files the lines all start with one space and two tabs. I tried removing the ^ before gene_height and it made it work, but now it deletes the space and two tabs which might break the formatting. Do you know how to account for that spacing?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the two values inside the curly-braces are always going to be after the string `"normal_height"`, and that there is nothing else inside the curly-braces:

(BTW, having `"normal_height"` twice seems odd to me, but that's what's in your sample text so that's what I'm going to use).

```perl
perl -pe 'BEGIN{ $gh_fmt = "gene_height={ \"normal_height\" %i  \"normal_height\" %i }" };
          s/gene_height\h*=\h*\{[^}]*\}/sprintf($gh_fmt, int(rand(51)+170), int(rand(51)+170))/e
          ' input.txt
```

Sample output:

```
                complexion={ "complexion_3" 60 "complexion_3" 132 }
                geneheight={ "normal_height" 216  "normal_height" 202 }
```

Notes:

- The `-p` option causes `perl` to operate similarly to `sed` - i.e. read each line of input, apply the code to each line, and then print the line whether modified or not.
- The `BEGIN {}` code block is executed only once before anything else is executed.  The remaining code is executed once per input line, in an implicit while-read type loop.
- On any input line containing `geneheight={`, it replaces the portion of that line between curly-braces with the desired text.   It does not change anything else in the line - i.e. it doesn't matter if the line is indented by a space, a tab, or a space and two tabs. It doesn't matter if it is indented at all, or whether there is other text on the same line before or after the `gene_height={...}` pattern.
- The `\{[^}]*\}` portion of the regex pattern matches a literal `{` character, zero-or-more characters that **AREN'T** a `}`, followed by a literal `}` character.  i.e. the entire `{...}` string.
- The search pattern uses `\h*` (zero-or-more horizontal whitespace characters) to cope with any optional whitespace around the `=` sign.  It will work as-is with your sample input, and it will also work if the input contains `gene_height = {` or similar. The output will always be consistent with the `$gh_fmt` string (i.e. no optional whitespace).
- NOTE: for this particular script which only reads one line at a time, the `\h` (horizontal whitespace) works exactly the same as `\s` (any whitespace, including newlines and form-feeds and more).  Perl, however, is capable of working with multi-line input, so it's worth remembering the distinction anyway.  See `man perlre` and search for `"Pattern White Space"`.

  A version of the script which slurped the entire file at once and applied the `s///` operation globally would look like:

  ```
  perl -0777 -pe '
     BEGIN{ $gh_fmt = "geneheight={ \"normal_height\" %i  \"normal_height\" %i }" };
     s/gene_height\s*=\s*\{[^}]*\}/sprintf($gh_fmt, int(rand(51)+170), int(rand(51)+170))/mge
     ' input.txt
  ```

  This version would be able to cope with input that contained any kind of whitespace, including newlines, before or after the `=` sign, or even within the `{...}` string.  Note the addition of the `m` modifier for multi-line string and the `g` modifier to match globally (i.e. match all occurrences in the input)
- perl's `e` modifier to the `s///` search and replace operator is used.  It causes the right-hand-side (RHS), the replacement string, to be evaluated as perl code.  i.e. it runs the `sprintf()` function.  See `man perlop` and search for `"s/PATTERN/REPLACEMENT/msixpodualngcer"`
- I could have put the format string directly into the `sprintf()` function.  Instead, I chose to use a variable (`$gh_fmt`, defined in a BEGIN block) because IMO it makes it more readable.  It also makes it more obvious how to extend the script to handle more patterns (just add more format strings and more `s///` operations).
- `int(rand(51))` returns a random number from 0 to 50.  Add that to 170, and it gives a random number between 170 and 220.  See `perldoc -f rand`.
- The script will work with stdin and/or one or more input files.
- You can use perl's `-i` in-place-edit option to cause it to change the input file(s) instead of printing to stdout.   See `man perlrun` for details on how -i works.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk (which I assume you have since you're apparently using GNU sed given the script i your question) for the 3rd arg to `match()` and `\<` word boundaries:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { min=170; max=220; range=max-min+1; srand() }
match($0,/(.*\<gene_height=.* )[0-9]+(.* )[0-9]+(.*)/,a) {
    x = int( min + rand()*range )
    y = int( min + rand()*range )
    $0 = a[1] x a[2] y a[3]
}
{ print }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
        complexion={ "complexion_3" 60 "complexion_3" 132 }
        gene_height={ "normal_height" 198 "normal_height" 183 }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
        complexion={ "complexion_3" 60 "complexion_3" 132 }
        gene_height={ "normal_height" 197 "normal_height" 205 }
```

If you want to do "inplace" editing just add `-i inplace`, and of course you don't need to store the script in a file so you could just do:

```
awk -i inplace '
    BEGIN { min=170; max=220; range=max-min+1; srand() }
    match($0,/(.*\<gene_height=.* )[0-9]+(.* )[0-9]+(.*)/,a) {
        x = int( min + rand()*range )
        y = int( min + rand()*range )
        $0 = a[1] x a[2] y a[3]
    }
    { print }
' *.txt
```